# extraction of minimal bounding box

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bounding-box

I've got a volume (image) and a minimal bounding box which is wrapping a certain structure. 
I used the following algorithm to extract the minimal bounding box

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18264-minimal-bounding-box/content/minboundbox.m

So that I get a bounding box which looks like this

[image: Minimal Bounding Box in the volume space]

Now, I want to create a new volume from the MBB. In other words, I want to map every point within the MBB to a new box which is axis-parallel.

I can get the dimensions of the new box from the corner points

```
 dim = [0 0 0];
 x = cp(:,1);
 y = cp(:,2);
 z = cp(:,3);
 dim(3) = sqrt( (x(1)-x(2))^2 + (y(1)-y(2))^2 + (z(1)-z(2))^2 );
 dim(1) = sqrt( (x(1)-x(4))^2 + (y(1)-y(4))^2 + (z(1)-z(4))^2 );
 dim(2) = sqrt( (x(1)-x(5))^2 + (y(1)-y(5))^2 + (z(1)-z(5))^2 );
```

Now, I can apply the rotation matrix returned by the minboundbox algorithm,

```
 A = zeros(4,4); A(1:3, 1:3) = R; A(4,4) = 1;
 tform = affine3d(A);
 N = numel(img);
 [X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(img), 1:N);
 V = img(1:N);
 [Xt, Yt, Zt] = transformPointsForward (tform,X,Y,Z);
 Xt = reshape(Xt, size(img));
 Yt = reshape(Yt, size(img));
 Zt = reshape(Zt, size(img));
```

And now I'm stuck. I need to:

- interpolate the values associated to these coordinates in a regular grid (any method I tried went OUT OF MEMORY, the image has the following size=(300,400,500));
- extract only the region of the MBB.

any idea how can I do that?

**UPDATE** the main problem was not how to get Xt, Yt, Zt...

the problem, since Xt, Yt and Zt form an irregular grid of points, with certain values associated, how can I get a regular grid with the interpolated point back? I tried this but it went out of memory

```
Vq = griddata(Xt, Yt, Zt, double(V), 1:dim(1), 1:dim(2), 1:dim(3));
```

Comment: How many points do you have? Have you tried just measuring how much memory you actually need to perform that command and see if your system even supports it first?

Comment: 31000000 points...give or take....
but, do they all have to fit in memory together at the same time? I think and I hope it's interpolating only locally and not globally.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no function that will interpolate locally without doing a loop manually through sub regions and performing interpolation. Yeah they do have to fit in memory+page file; Have you tried clearing out your old (X,Y,Z) data after transformation? That can save you memory.

Comment: yep, I didn't went out of memory, but it takes too long. I didnt manage to get the results (after 30 min I launched the command)

wait wait... if u do plain interpolation u dont need to load the whole thing. Do u? I might be wrong, I'm still studying this stuff :-)

Comment: Usually interpolation is local so yes. The region of points you need surrounding the interpolation region is dependent on the type of interpolation you do (higher order = more points needed).

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to map the space of the MBB to the unit cube if you want to extract only the region of the MBB. Here's how I would do it (note this is mostly pseudocode, won't guarantee it works. I'll try it out on my matlab instance on my other computer soon...)

```
Translation = eye(4)
Translation(1:3, 4) = transpose(-cornerpoints(1,:))

BoxAxisX = transpose(cornerpoints(:,4) - cornerpoints(:,1))
BoxAxisX = BoxAxisX / norm(BoxAxisX)

BoxAxisY = transpose(cornerpoints(:,5) - cornerpoints(:,1))
BoxAxisY = BoxAxisY / norm(BoxAxisY)

BoxAxisZ = transpose(cornerpoints(:,2) - cornerpoints(:,1))
BoxAxisZ = BoxAxisZ / norm(BoxAxisZ)

Rotation = eye(4)
Rotation(1:3,1:3) = [ BoxAxisX, BoxAxisY, BoxAxisZ ]

Scale = diag( [ (1/dim(1)) (1/dim(2)) (1/dim(3)) 1 ] )

A = affine3d( Scale * Rotation * Translation )

[Xt, Yt, Zt] = transformPointsForward (A,X,Y,Z);

% Now all your points that are within the box should satisfy unit constraints
GoodIndices = Xt <= 1 && Xt >= 0 && Yt <= 1 && Yt >= 0 && Zt <= 1 && Zt >= 0
GoodX = Xt(GoodIndices)
...
```

The general idea is to turn the box back into a unit cube with one point on the origin. Here are the steps:

- Choose a base point; this will become your origin.
- Find vectors from the base point that form the bounds of the box; this is your current coordinate frame.
- Construct the rotation matrix from those vectors; This is the matrix going from the standard basis vector (X,Y,Z) to your box rotation using the base point you've chosen. Invert this matrix.
- Translate the box back such that the base point is now at the origin
- Now use that inverted rotation matrix and apply that to your box.
- Note your box is now axis aligned at the origin. Now all you need to do is scale your box appropriately.

The reason why I don't use the rotation matrix they give is that I don't really know which axis it will go towards and what point it rotates around (rotating around the origin! what!). So... It is just easier to construct the rotation matrix using the corner points you know allowing you to choose the base point.

As for the Out of Memory Exceptions...there are lot of posts on how to reduce memory usage. That image size is huge though..(~240MB)

Comment: Ok, but the main problem was not how to get Xt, Yt, Zt (even though I really appreciate ur method which is more cleaver than mine)

the problem, since Xt, Yt and Zt form an irregular grid of points, with certain values associated, how can I get a regular grid with the interpolated point back? 

I'll add this to the question